# SWIG incorrectly using a generated pointer type when generating Java code from C. How to change the interface file?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

It seems like SWIG is generating a pointer type, which then is used even when only a value itself is needed by the function. It does this by creating a function requiring the pointer type in Java, then passing its CPtr value to the generated wrapper function. However, this functions expects a pointer, not its value, and therefore leads to a Segmentation Fault. The Java file is a translation of a C file, that has been tested and works without problem. Accordingly, the problem is most likely not in the native code. I will omit it here, since the function is about 100 lines long.
Here are the important parts of the various files:

In Main.java :

```
      bitwuzla.bitwuzla_set_option(bzla, BitwuzlaOption.BITWUZLA_OPT_INCREMENTAL, new SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t(1, false));
```

The generated type:

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t {
  private transient long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t(long cPtr, @SuppressWarnings("unused") boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

The generated wrapper, of which only jarg3 and its handling is important:

```
SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_bitwuzlaJNI_bitwuzla_1set_1option(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jint jarg2, jlong jarg3) {
  Bitwuzla *arg1 = (Bitwuzla *) 0 ;
  BitwuzlaOption arg2 ;
  uint32_t arg3 ;
  uint32_t *argp3 ;
  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  arg1 = *(Bitwuzla **)&jarg1; 
  arg2 = (BitwuzlaOption)jarg2; 
  argp3 = *(uint32_t **)&jarg3;

  printf("jarg3: %ld\n", jarg3); // 1

  printf("argp3: %p\n", (void *)argp3); // 0x1

  if (!argp3) {
    SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaNullPointerException, "Attempt to dereference null uint32_t");
    return ;
  }
  arg3 = *argp3; // The program crashes here, since it is trying to dereference 0x1
  bitwuzla_set_option(arg1,arg2,arg3);
}
```

The native function:

```
void
bitwuzla_set_option(Bitwuzla *bitwuzla, BitwuzlaOption option, uint32_t value)
```

The SWIG interface file is fairly basic so far:

```
%module bitwuzla
%{
#include "bitwuzla.h"
%}

typedef struct Bitwuzla Bitwuzla;

%include "bitwuzla.h"
```

And the error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1e74706a60, pid=28005, tid=28006
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.19+7) (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libbitwuzla.so+0x47a60]  Java_bitwuzlaJNI_bitwuzla_1set_1option+0x9e
```

The code does run if I change the wrapping file as follows:

```
arg3 = *(uint32_t *)&jarg3;
bitwuzla_set_option(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

However, changing all occorunces of this mistake manually seems labor intensive and prone to errors.
I have looked through the SWIG documentation, specifically on typemaps, but it doesn't seem like anything addresses what to do if SWIG simply improperly uses a pointer type. I am hesitant to simply change the pointer type to a long type, since the native code does use uint32 pointers as well. Is there a specific way of modifying the interface file to change SWIGs behaviour regarding this type?

Comment: If your generated code needs changes, this might mean that the input to the code generator is wrong. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Provide all code and commands needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you tell SWIG what the definition of `uint32_t` was?  `%include <stdint.i>`.  For unknown types SWIG creates opaque pointers to the type.

Comment: Note that even if `bitwuzla.h` included `stdint.h`, SWIG *does not* recurse when generating wrappers via `%include` for the simple reason that you wouldn't want all of `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h` or whatever else was included to be wrapped.  There is an `-includeall` switch, but it is generally not what you want.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, that was the answer, thank you very much! I did use the -includeall switch, but I guess it was indeed not what I wanted. But with using -includeall and adding the libraries to the interface file it works perfectly. Thanks!